# A hyperledger fabric question regarding ledger database

Tags: database, hash, hyperledger-fabric

How to include data hashes in peer ledger and store the actual data in a centralised database, instead of the whole copy of state data in every peer, to save space and improve scalability.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it "manually" with you client and/or application. You should have a Smart Contract with its structs and, there, you will registry the hash of the data that you mention.

To develop your client and/or application, you should use [Hyperledger Fabric's SDK](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/fabric-sdks.html).

Comment: Hi, I was also thinking of the same solution. I was thinking of having a IPFS database network and use only the hashes of those in the HLF peers.

Answer (score 0):

To include data hashes in peer ledger and store the actual data into another side database, You can use Private data management system of hyperledger fabric.
In the following tutorial, you can find details about Private data and why we need it.

Link: https://medium.com/coinmonks/private-public-data-at-hyperledger-fabric-v1-4-ff9f303f4bc1

Besides that, you can do it manually by using chaincode and client apps.

Comment: Is private data management in particular more suitable for storing data hashes or a manual approach is better.

Comment: Hyperledger Fabric has plugable architecture and everything is depends on your use cases. If you want to hide data from others, than private data management  will be perfect and you need not to develop anything from scratch. The throughput of hyperledger fabric is not good yet(hopefully it'll be good in future release), so to save space and improve scalability, you may follow manual approach. In future, their might be support for offchain data.